# Throwing and handling error from multer-gridfs-storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I am throwing an error from multer-gridfs-storage , but not sure about handling it in a better way .

My Code :-

```js
const storage = new gridfsStorage({
    url : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/uploadeditems' ,
    options : { useNewUrlParser : true , useUnifiedTopology : true  } ,
    file : (req , file) => {
        if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
            return {
                filename : file.originalname,
                bucketName : 'Images' ,
                metadata : {
                    ownername : "Anshu Anand"
                }
            }
        }
        else if(file.mimetype === 'application/pdf') {
            return {
                filename : file.originalname , 
                bucketName : 'projectPDFs'
            }
        }

        else {
            throw new Error("File type is different")
        }
    }
})

upload = multer({
    storage ,
    
})
```

My api to handle it :-

```js
app.post('/upload' , upload.single('project')  , async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    

    res.render('upload' , {
            msg : "File has been uploaded successfully"
        })
} ,

(err , req , res , next ) => {

    console.log(err) 

  return res.send(err) //gives just this :- storageError : [] 
  
)
```

**console.log(err)** output :-

```
Error: File type is different
at GridFSStorage.file [as _file] (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\index.js:41:19)
at GridFSStorage._generate (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:472:18)
at GridFSStorage.fromStream (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:368:35)
at GridFSStorage.fromFile (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:353:15)
at GridFSStorage._handleFile (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:314:9)
at F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:144:17
at allowAll (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\multer\index.js:8:3)
at wrappedFileFilter (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\multer\index.js:44:7)
at Busboy.<anonymous> (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
at Busboy.emit (node:events:376:20)
at Busboy.emit (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
at PartStream.<anonymous> (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
at PartStream.emit (node:events:376:20)
at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
at HeaderParser.emit (node:events:376:20)
at HeaderParser._finish (F:\Node Projects\upload-download\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8) {
 storageErrors: []
 }
```

So how do I handle it in a better way and send my exact error which is being thrown in storage config ?

Thanks in advance for any help .

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to get that exact message .
You can get it on message property of err .

```
console.log(err.message) //=>File type is different
```